I am trying to get the arrow button conditionally if the screen size is smaller or the more steps is coming in, but its not working

I am trying to get the arrow button back and forth conditionally if the screen size is smaller or the more steps is coming in, also if there is no step beyond then the arrow should not shown, but its not working in my current implementations,
export const StatusStepper = ({ activeStep, steps, handleStepClick }) ={
    const stepperRef = useRef(null);
    const [showLeftArrow, setShowLeftArrow] = useState(false);
    const [showRightArrow, setShowRightArrow] = useState(false);

    const checkArrows = () ={
        if (stepperRef.current) {
            setShowLeftArrow(stepperRef.current.scrollLeft 0);
            setShowRightArrow(stepperRef.current.scrollLeft < stepperRef.current.scrollWidth - stepperRef.current.clientWidth);
        }
    };

    const scrollStepper = (direction) ={
        if (stepperRef.current) {
            const stepWidth = stepperRef.current.clientWidth / steps.length;
            const scrollAmount = direction === 'left' ? -stepWidth : stepWidth;
            stepperRef.current.scrollBy({
                left: scrollAmount,
                behavior: 'smooth',
            });
        }
    };

    useEffect(() ={
        checkArrows();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() ={
        const handleResize = () ={
            checkArrows();
        };

        window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);

        return () ={
            window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="stepper-container">
            {showLeftArrow && (
                <div className="arrow-container" onClick={() =scrollStepper('left')}>
                    <ArrowBackIosIcon />
                </div>
            )}
            <div className="stepper-content" ref={stepperRef}>
                <div className="breadcrumb">
                    {steps.map((step, index) =(
                        <a
                            key={index}
                            href="#"
                            onClick={() =handleStepClick(index, step.status)}
                            className={`${activeStep === index ? 'active' : ''}`}
                            style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
                        >
                            <span className="breadcrumb__inner">
                                <span className="breadcrumb__title">{step.title}</span>
                                {/* <span className="badge" style={{
                                    backgroundColor: activeStep === index ? '#fff' : '#255F79',
                                    color: activeStep === index ? '#255F79' : '#fff',
                                    fontSize: '0.75rem',
                                }}>
                                    {step.counts}
                                </span*/}
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>
            {showRightArrow && (
                <div className="arrow-container" onClick={() =scrollStepper('right')}>
                    <ArrowForwardIosIcon />
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

I tried to use the window.addEventListener but it's not working.

Can you provide minimal working example URL in some online code editor?

You have 6 syntax errors. Arrow functions are defined like () => { ... }, not like () = { ... }. Please edit the snippet, retry and adapt the question if it doesn't solve
